# Makefile Windows: .. is not recognized as an internal or external command when changing directory

Tags: windows, makefile, gnu-make

I'm seeing a strange issue when trying to change directory from inside a Makefile in Windows. My pseudo-code is as follows:-

```
all:
    cd ../ProjectDir && ../AutoExc InputFile.h
```

Where AutoExc is an executable that I have in the parent directory. When I run 'make' from the command line, I see the following output:-

```
cd ../ProjectDir && ../AutoExc InputFile.h
'..' is not recognized as an internal or external command.
```

The strange thing is that running this exact Makefile in Linux works. I have also tried running the above command from the command line in Windows and it worked, so there isn't an issue with 'cd' for example.

Any idea why this is happening and what can I do to get it to work? If there's an issue with the version of Make, is there another more reliable mechanism to change directory and run an executable on Windows?

I am using Make version 3.81 on Windows 7 (latest) and Make version 4.1 on Linux 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu. I have 'cd' installed as part of 'Git for Windows', the git version is 2.16.1.windows.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command contains shell characters and is passed down to `cmd.exe`:

```
>cd ../Public &&  ../test
'..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

>cd ../Public &&  ..\test
'..\test' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

i.e. `cmd.exe` interprets `../test` as command `..` with option `/test`.

I guess one solution would to apply a macro to command names with paths, e.g. (*note*: untested, just typed from my head):

```
if (...I'm running under Windows...)
  convert_path = $(subst /,\\,$(1))
else
  convert_path = $(1)
endif

all:
    cd ../ProjectDir && $(call convert_path,../AutoExc) InputFile.h
```

or, if possible, use the suggestion from the comments `SHELL := /bin/sh`, or whatever the correct path is to a UNIX compatible shell in your Windows environment. "Git for Windows" is AFAIR based on MinGW, so you should have `bash` available.

Comment: The workaround is probably to explicitly say `SHELL=/bin/sh` in your Makefile, though I would have thought this was already the default on any sane platform, and then on Windows too.